# Customize touch feedback in Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I have my style defined as follows:

```
<style name="actionBarTheme" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_style</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/actionBarTitleText</item>
</style>
```

And the actionBar is actually of the color defined in button_style (correctly working in other parts of the code). The problem is that the items are not working correctly (the background color is too light).

Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks

EDIT:

[image: example]

In the picture there is the touch-feedback that I have now. The button_style has another touch effect (a darker one) since this is almost invisible.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you have now and what you want changed? perhaps with pictures.

Comment: I've added the details

Answer (score 1):

You can have this affect with `actionButtonStyle`

```
<style name="appTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/actionButtonTheme</item>
</style>
```

and then place your button style as the background of that.

```
<style name="actionButtonTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_style</item>
</style>
```

You will still need to set the background of your action bar but this only needs to be a colour or drawable image as that is all that will actually be used.

Comment: have you tried it? Does it work for you? I still have the same result :( this is my styles.xml file if you want to check it: http://pastebin.com/hLq7JsGZ Thanks however for the answer!

Comment: ah no ok! Now it works! Can I customize also the backbutton for the same result? :) thanks!

Comment: probably by using `android:homeAsUpIndicator`

Comment: I've tried with that, both putting another actionBackButtonTheme and directly the drawable/buttonstyle inside it.. but they won't work :(

Comment: This answer of mine might work instead then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342808/how-to-make-action-bar-icon-change-when-clicked/19461102#19461102

Comment: it doesn't work correctly since it will work only for the logo and not for the whole back button (text included) :( Thx btw! :)